# How to use parameter in strftim() function in sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room, strftime

I'm using Room library in an android project. How can I use the method parameter in strftime() function (something like `:period days` instead of `7 days`)?

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM purchase " +
        "WHERE date >= strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day', '7 days')")
List<Purchase> getPurchases(int period);                               \\ ☝ //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With string concatenation:

```
strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day', :period || ' days')
```